# React.js Escaping Characters Inside State Which Contain Backticks

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, state, testcafe

Please consider the following state (and assume this is in a React.js script):

```
// example A

this.state = {

value1 : `fixture `MyFixture`
    .page `file:///user/my-website/index.html`;`, 


    }
```

There are backticks contained in the string of `value1`.  Normally, it works, like so:

```
// example B

this.state = {

value1 : `an ordinary string`, 


    }
```

Unfortunately, due to there being backticks ***within*** my string, it's causing example A to be invalid and obviously I need to figure out how to escape such characters within the state.

I have attempted the recommended `` {`a string`} `` to escape it but it doesn't appear valid either, see:

```
this.state = {

value1 : `fixture {``MyFixture`
    .page `file:///user/my-website/index.html`;`}`, 


    }
```

The `.page`part is supposed to be part of the string.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: scape the ` with \, like so `fixture \`MyFixture\` ....

Comment: Thank you @tpsilva! That solved it.  The solution is here:  ```this.state = {
      
value1 : `fixture \`MyFixture\`
    .page \`file:///user/my-website/index.html\`;`, 


    }```